# Counting letter occurrences in words

Tags: java, string, char

I'm attempting to make my program in java count the number of letters in each word. Right now I have it counting words, not letters. Any help to get it to do letters would be great!

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LetterTypeCount 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create HashMap to store String keys and Integer values
        Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>();

        createMap(myMap); // create map based on user input
        displayMap(myMap); // display map content
    }

    // create map from user input
    private static void createMap(Map<String, Integer> map)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // create scanner
        System.out.println("Enter a string:"); // prompt for user input
        String input = scanner.nextLine();

        // tokenize the input
        String[] tokens = input.split(" ");

        // processing input text
        for (String token : tokens)
        {
            String letter = token.toLowerCase(); // get lowercase letter

            // if the map contains the letter
            if (map.containsKey(letter)) // is letter in map
            {
                int count = map.get(letter); // get current count
                map.put(letter, count + 1); // increment count
            }
            else
                map.put(letter, 1); // add new letter with a count of 1 to map
        }
    }

    // display map content
    private static void displayMap(Map<String, Integer> map)
    {
        Set<String> keys = map.keySet(); // get keys

        // sort keys
        TreeSet<String> sortedKeys = new TreeSet<>(keys);

        System.out.printf("%nMap contains:%nKey\t\tValue%n");

        // generate output for each key in map
        for (String key : sortedKeys)
            System.out.printf("%-10s%10s%n", key, map.get(key));
        System.out.printf("%nsize: %d%nisEmpty: %b%n",
                map.size(), map.isEmpty());
    }
} // end class LetterTypeCount
```

I'm thinking I need to use the String charAt method somewhere

Comment: you could simply use the `String.length()` Method after you did split it into words and add them together

Comment: You want to count letters occurrences?

Comment: Are you trying to just count letters, and ignore spaces, numbers, and punctuation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might not be very elegant but:

```
public class LetterTypeCount 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create HashMap to store String keys and Integer values
        Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>();

        createMap(myMap); // create map based on user input
        displayMap(myMap); // display map content
    }

    // create map from user input
    private static void createMap(Map<String, Integer> map)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // create scanner
        System.out.println("Enter a string:"); // prompt for user input
        String input = scanner.nextLine();

        // split to words
        String[] words = input.split(" ");
        for (String word : words) 
        {
            word = word.toLowerCase(); // get lowercase word
            for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++) 
            {
                char c = word.charAt(i); //get char at position i
                if (map.containsKey(c + "")) // is letter in map
                {
                    int count = map.get(c + ""); // get current count
                    map.put(c + "", count + 1); // increment count
                }
                else
                    map.put(c + "", 1); // add new letter with a count of 1 to map
            }
            // if the map contains the letter
        }
    }

    // display map content
    private static void displayMap(Map<String, Integer> map)
    {
        Set<String> keys = map.keySet(); // get keys

        // sort keys
        TreeSet<String> sortedKeys = new TreeSet<>(keys);

        System.out.printf("%nMap contains:%nKey\t\tValue%n");

        // generate output for each key in map
        for (String key : sortedKeys)
            System.out.printf("%-10s%10s%n", key, map.get(key));
        System.out.printf("%nsize: %d%nisEmpty: %b%n",
                map.size(), map.isEmpty());
    }
} // end class LetterTypeCount
```

Comment: under the if and else statements, it won't compile because char cannot be converted to a string

Comment: Change map generics to Map<Character, Integer> as I did up there. Or if you want to keep strings then simplest solution would be: map.put(c + "", 1);

Comment: That worked, although it only counts unique characters and doesn't actually increment

Comment: Updated with whole code (just add imports). 100% sure it works.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that you count latin chars only:

```
public int[] letters = new int['z' - 'a' + 1];

// count chars:
for (String token : tokens) 
    for (char c : token.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) 
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
            letters[c - 'a']++;

// then print out counts:
for (int i = 0; i < 'z' - 'a' + 1; i++) 
    if (letters[i] > 0)
        System.out.format("%s occurs %s time(s)\n", (char)('a' + i), letters[i]);
```

This looks a bit "low-level", but this is working Java code (just tested!), which uses interchangeability of `char`s and `int`s on arithmetical operations.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `for` loop and add +1 for each letter to an array or a `HashMap`containing the letter occurance.

```
for(int i=0; i<= input.length(); i++){
mymap.put(input.charAt(i), myMap.get(input.charAt(i)+1));
}
```

But then you should define your variable `myMap` global and not inside your main method.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Java 8 [**Stream API**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html)
Besides Java streams you also should know Java [**Lambda Expressions**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

```
String input = "ANY String";
    Map<String, Long> map = Arrays.stream(input.split("")) // Stream String
            .map(String::toLowerCase) // All letters to lower case
            .filter(letter -> !letter.equals(" ")) // Remove spaces
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `str.length()` like so:

```
System.out.println(key.length());
```

Comment: Tried this, it had an "error: cannot find symbol System.out.printf("%d", key.length); variable key"

Comment: @user3434743 its key.length()

Comment: That's actually what I tried as well, still the same error though.

Comment: @user3434743 i edited my answer, check it out, and let me know what you get.

Comment: Still the same error unfortunately.

Comment: @user3434743 you should have something since key is a string, try this last thing from me